# DataGridView and ComboBox problem

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm filling a ComboBox with DataGridView cells' values. Now, I don't want to repeat values which already are in the ComboBox.

So, there is for example:

- Bill Gates
- Steave Jobs
- Steave Ballmer
- Steave Jobs

I want to remove all values which appear more than once.

This is my code:

```
private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList SellerNameList = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        SellerNameList.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cSellerName"].Value);
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = SellerNameList;
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you want a unique list for the `dataSource` for your ComboBox. If you are using .NET 3 and above you can use:

```
List<T> withDupes = SellerNameList;
List<T> noDupes = withDupes.Distinct().ToList();

comboBox1.DataSource = noDupes;
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would be via a collection and LINQ , i would say.

[Try this link for an introduction](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-4)